# convert string to variable within prepared statement

Tags: php, mysql, csv, upload

I am creating a php script that imports a csv file into an existing mySQL database.

I am selecting the matching column headings by checking if the heading in in an array and trying to use the column number to create my input into my prepared statement.

```
while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ",")) !== FALSE) {
$numCols = count($data);
$row     = array();

// process the first row to select columns for extraction
if($isFirstRow) {
        $num = count($data);
        for($col=0; $col<count($columns); $col++){
            for($c=0; $c<$numCols; $c++)

                if(!in_array($data[$c], $columns[$col])){
                    if($c == ($numCols-1))
                        {
                            $matchingCol[$col] = '""';
                        }
                    }
                    else{
                        $matchingCol[$col] = 'data['.$c.']';
                         apc_store("foo$c", $matchingCol[$col]);
                }

        }

    $isFirstRow = false;
}

$data = array(
'contractorName' => (apc_fetch('foo1')) ,
'contractorType' => $matchingCol[3]); 
$query = "INSERT INTO uploadSQL SET" . bindFields($data);

$result = $pdo->prepare($query); 
$result->execute($data);
```

The data posted into the database is `'$data[3]'`, `'$data[5]'` etc.
How can I get the INSERT to input the data stored at `$data[3]` and not the string `'$data[3]'`?

Comment: Use `$data[$c]` instead of `'data['.$c.']'`...!?

Comment: @deceze please post your answers as answer not comments. As more often the comments are ignored and it makes the answers hard to find for other people.

Comment: @Harish I do if I think the answer is worth it and I'm sure it's the answer. This here is more a shot in the dark, since the question is rather vague despite there being too much code.

Answer (score 0):

```
Use $data[$c] instead of 'data['.$c.']'...!?
```

Single quoted strings will display things almost completely "as is." Variables and most escape sequences will not be interpreted.

Comment: @deceze  If I use $data[$c] instead of 'data['.$c.']' it takes the string from the first row, i.e. the column title and inserts it in each row in the database.

Answer (score 0):

Not an exact solution to the problem but a work around. I'm sure there's a more efficient way.

```
 if($isFirstRow) {
        $csvRow1 = $data;
    }
                            $num = count($data);


            for($col=0; $col<count($columns); $col++){
                for($c=0; $c<$numCols; $c++){

                    if(!in_array($csvRow1[$c], $columns[$col])){
                                                if($c == ($numCols-1))
                        {
                            $matchingCol[$col] = '""';
                        }
                    }
                    else{

                            $matchingCol[$col] = "$data[$c]";
                            $c = $numCols;
                    }
                }
            }
```